# How to store multiple lines of output in separate variables?

Tags: bash, shell

```
$ external_tool | grep -iE "id1|id2"
id1 Z55Hsh1abm
id2 sFXxu4KzkJbXab08UT
```

I have to store each *id1* and *id2* in separate variables mentioned below without executing `external_tool` twice. Below is how I am doing now but that's not acceptable.

```
export VAR1=$(external_tool | grep -i id1 | awk '{print $2}')
export VAR2=$(external_tool | grep -i id2 | awk '{print $2}')
```

Desired output from above should be

```
$ echo $VAR1
Z55Hsh1abm
$ echo $VAR2
sFXxu4KzkJbXab08UT
```

How do I store them in separate variables and export them in env var?

Comment: So what is your problem? What is `client_secret` and where is `id2` gone?

Comment: sorry @tshiono its id2 really , my only problem is I can't run the tool again (meaning external_tool can only be run once) so I need to be able to get the output in the desired format.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback. Your requirement is understood. Would you please test my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r id val; do
    if [[ $id = "id1" ]]; then
        export var1=$val
    elif [[ $id = "id2" ]]; then
        export var2=$val
    fi
done < <(external_tool | grep -iE "id1|id2")

echo "$var1"
echo "$var2"
```

- The basic concept is to keep the id's as the output of the command and switch the variable to assign depending on the value of `id`.
- The `<(command)` expression is a process substitution and you can redirect the output of the `command` to the `while` loop.

Please note that it is not recommended to use uppercases as a normal variable. That is why I've modified them as `var1` and `var2`.

Answer (score 2):

You may get this done in a single call to external utility using process substitution using `awk`:

```sh
read -r var1 var2 < <(external_tool | awk -v ORS=' ' '$1~/^(id1|id2)$/{print $2}')

# check variables
declare -p var1 var2
```

Comment: This is also a acceptable solution in my case , I changed the last declare to got them in my own vars. but works perfectly in single line.